# Pyramid and perpendicular planes

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I need help with the following problem.

Given a pyramid ABCDM. The opposite planes (ABM) and (DCM) are perpendicular to the base ABCD. The base ABCD is trapezoid (AD || BC) and AD=3 cm., BC=5 cm. If the area of the triangles ABM and BCM is $20 cm^2 $  and $9 cm.^2$, find the volume of the pyramid ABCDM.

[image]

Comment: Hint. Using the given data, it is easy to draw a picture. Under all circumstances, if possible, draw a picture.

Comment: Done. I am not sure if the volume can be determined. We have too little data.